# Create a 2D PHP array within a while loop

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a prepared statement to draw information from a database. There are 3 fields of information drawn from the database and an unknown number of rows.

I have a 'while' loop to define what should happen to the information gained from each row. I would like to create an array for the 3 fields of information to sit in for each row, then an array for all of these arrays to sit in (i.e. a 2D array).

Here's my code so far:

```
$bArray = [];
$bList = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT blog_title,blog_date,blog_id FROM cms_blog');
$bList->execute();
$bList->bind_result($bListTitle,$bListDate,$bListId);
while ($bList->fetch()) {
  $bArray['bTitle']=$bListTitle;
  $bArray['bDate']=$bListDate;
  $bArray['bId']=$bListId;
}
```

I would like the array to look something like this once complete:

```
Array (
  Array (
    [blogTitle] => First title
    [blogDate] => First date
    [blogId] => First ID
  )
  Array (
    [blogTitle] => Second title
    [blogDate] => Second date
    [blogId] => Second ID
  )
)
```

Is there a way to write this? I only need key pairs for the inner arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$bArray = array();
$bList = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT blog_title,blog_date,blog_id FROM cms_blog');
$bList->execute();
$bList->bind_result($bListTitle,$bListDate,$bListId);
while ($bList->fetch()) {
  $iArray=array();  // Inner array
  $iArray['bTitle']=$bListTitle;
  $iArray['bDate']=$bListDate;
  $iArray['bId']=$bListId;
  $bArray[] = $iArray;   // Insert the inner array into $bArray
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly thanks! Just out of curiousity, is it better to declare the array variables like `$bArray = [];` or `$bArray = array();`?

Comment: sorry, I don't know what's better. I use array() and it works ;)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to use this:

```
for ($row = 0; $row < 3; $row++)
{
    for ($col = 0; $col < 3; $col++)
    {
        $var[$row][$col]="col: ".$col." Row: ".$row;
    }
}
```